# Sidebar is not visible in storybook server

Tags: react-native, storybook

I am creating a React Native mobile app with **storybook.js**. But when I run the command `yarn run storybook`, the storybook server starts running on the **port: 7007**

[Preview and components in the sidebar are not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmZUQ.png)

but it does not show the components. But it does show the preview in android emulator.

[components are visible in sidebar and visible in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVAlT.png)

I need to see the preview on browser, but it does not at lease show the components at least.

Can somebody please help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and solved it by making sure storybook and the emulator were running on the same port.

I set the port/host when configuring StorybookUIRoot then added the host to storybook command in the package.json `"storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007 -h 192.168.1.8"`

Restart storybook and the mobile app, you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

looks like your are experiencing a common issue. See this pinned issue from the [repo](https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/issues/55).

Also to be clear the server and this web ui is not required to use react native storybook and you can use it entirely from the ondeviceUI.

There are a few things you need to do to make sure that the stories load on the server.

First you should make sure the ondevice storybook is running before you start the server.

If you are still having issues you can manually specify the port and ip address

First set the ip and port on the getStorybookUI call.

```
const StorybookUIRoot = getStorybookUI({
 host: "192.111.1.11", // replace this ip address with your local ip address
  port: "7007"
});
```

Then adjust the script used to launch the server to have the port and ip option. Make sure that you use exactly the same port and host that you used in the previous step otherwise it won't work.

It should look something like this but with your own IP address instead.

```
"storybook": "start-storybook -p 7007 -h 192.111.1.11"
```

If none of this helps feel free to ask questions on the storybook discord in the react-native channel and I'll be there to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the [storybook tutorial](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/), try removing your `yarn.lock`, `yarn` again, and then follow Danny's answer.